# The value of $a/b+b/a-ab$ under the condition $ab=a-b$ (AMC 10 problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I am confused about the problem below. I answered correctly but used substitution to solve instead of changing everything to the same denominator as shown in the solution.

The problem: Two non-zero real numbers, a and b, satisfy ab = a - b. Which of the following is a possible value of
[image: (a/b)+(b/a)-ab]

This is the solution that was given to me:

[image: the solution]

My question is how the solution went from Step 2 to Step 3(I'm counting each line as a step). Forgive me if the answer to my question should've been really obvious to me. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: They substituted $(a-b)$ for $(ab)$.

Comment: From Step 2 to Step 3, we replace $(ab)^2 $ by $(a - b)^2$.

Comment: But how is ab equal to a-b?

Comment: The statement of the problem says, "Two non-zero real numbers, $a$ and $b$, satisfy ${\color{red}{ab = a-b}}.$